# How to transpose sas proc report output

Tags: sas

I have created a report (proc report) and all efforts (after going to google university) to transpose my data went miserably wrong.

```
proc report data=dataset1;
where cluster_id=1;
column ORGANISATION_CODE 
   ORGANISATION_NAME 
   ORG_TYPE
   org_type_name 
   CLUSTER_ID 
   CLUSTER_NAME 
   CLUSTER_TYPE 
   CountOFD
   CountOFC;
  define ORGANISATION_CODE / display 'Organisation Code' CENTER
  style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
     define ORGANISATION_NAME  / display 'Organisation Name' lEFT
    style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
     define org_type_name  /display 'Organisation Type' CENTER
style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
     define  org_type_name /display 'Organisation Type Name' CENTER
style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
     define CLUSTER_TYPE / display 'Cluster Type' CENTER
style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
      define CLUSTER_NAME / display 'Cluster Name' CENTER
style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
       define CLUSTER_ID / display 'Cluster ID' CENTER
style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
        define CountOFD / display 'CountOFD' CENTER
style(column)={width=1.5in} ;
        define CountOFC / display 'CountOFD' CENTER
style(column)={width=1.5in} ;       
run;
ods html close;
```

Comment: You're going to need to explain a bit more of what you're talking about.  What are you aiming for here?  Why do you use the word "transpose" (meaning convert rows to columns or columns to rows)?  I don't see any transpose happening here.

Comment: You will want to also look at `Proc TABULATE`.  Can you add some sample data and example of expected output.

Comment: sorry i am trying to paste a table from excel but ...having probs

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Joe, I need more information.

Did you try the **across** option on the **define** statement, along with stacking columns on the **column** statement?  See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1pl56sdqo09cyn1fifuhcz8dl2f.htm

If that doesn't work, then see PROC TRANSPOSE.